# My Screen is not good on white background

Tags: display

My monitor is having a hard time showing all the details when there is a white background

Take this image:
[image]

Here there is an image in the background however my monitor can't see it. What can I do to improve this

my monitor is :

```
Asus tuf vg279Ql1a
```

update if I in the HTML make a backdrop like this:
[image]

Then I can actually see the crown :(

Comment: Can you show us a photo of what you see so we can compare? Feel free to create an empty word document or text document with some example text so you don't have to blank out anything.

Comment: Every monitor has hardware controls to change brightness and contrast. Most likely those controls are totally misconfigured. Change then according to the calibration helper: https://www.hellotech.com/guide/for/how-to-calibrate-monitor-windows-10

Comment: @LPChip i can basically see all the same but not the background crown

Comment: @Robert i dont think its the windows calibration because if I put on an old screen I can actually see it just fine. I have also played with the contrast and brightness but can't seem to find a point where I can see the watermark

Comment: @Robert is correct though, if you can't see the grey crown because it appears white, there is too much contrast. Reduce contrast to as low as you need and use RGB 100% for all colors to compensate for the lack of brightness.

Comment: @LPChip even with Contrast 0 i still cant see the crown :(

Comment: Also check brightness and if it exists gamma setting of your monitor. Most monitors a way too bright by default.

Comment: @Robert i feel like ive adjuset the hell out of it with both brightness = 0 and contrast = 0 :S

Comment: @Robert ive updated my question

Comment: The 4th of 5 buttons (shortcut 2) is default for GameVisual menu. Set this to sRGB and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The contrast is set too high. You can adjust it using monitor's menu. It should be intuitive, but if it's not there are some instructions for using it in the [manual](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/LCD%20Monitors/VG279QL1A/ASUS_VG279Q1A_VG279QL1A_English.pdf).

Common default values for contrast are 50 and 75, depending on manufacturer and model. Ideally, you should [calibrate the display](http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/) for accurate color reproduction.

Comment: As for calibration: Windows has an excellent built-in display color calibration wizard.